# Unresolvable linking error E2065 with XXH32 (xxHash and lz4)

Tags: delphi, gcc, mingw, static-linking, delphi-xe3

I am currently updating/writing a [delphi binding for lz4 & xxHash](https://github.com/Hugie/lz4-delphi).

Project state with compiler error [is available here](https://github.com/Hugie/lz4-delphi/tree/5358ff58747159a261347b9b3d98bb369faa3555).

Not working line of xxHash.pas

```
function XXH32 (const AInput: Pointer; ALength: Integer; ASeed: Cardinal):  Cardinal; cdecl; external name '_XXH32';
```

When trying to bind function XXH32 from xxHash.o, it results in the error E2065.

```
[dcc32 Fehler] xxHash.pas(122): E2065 Ungenügende Forward- oder External-Deklaration: 'XXH32'
```

What i do not understand, all other functions are bound and working without problems.

When i analyze xxHash.o by creating a dumpfile, the function is present like every other of xxHash.o

Objdump command:

```
objdump -D xxhash.o > xxhash.o.txt
```

Dumpfile part of xxH32:

```
xxhash.o:     file format pe-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <_XXH32>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   57                      push   %edi
   2:   56                      push   %esi
   3:   53                      push   %ebx
   4:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
   7:   8b 44 24 28             mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
   b:   8b 4c 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%ecx
...
```

Any suggestions?

Minimal Implementation:

```
program lz4_minimal;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$L xxhash.o}

function XXH32 (const AInput: Pointer; ALength: Integer; ASeed: Cardinal):  Cardinal; cdecl; external name '_XXH32';
function XXH64 (const AInput: Pointer; ALength: Integer; ASeed: UInt64):    UInt64;   cdecl; external name '_XXH64';

//necessary dependencies
function  _malloc(size: cardinal): Pointer; cdecl;
begin
  GetMem(Result, size);
end;

procedure _memcpy(dest, source: Pointer;  count: Integer); cdecl;
begin
  Move(source^, dest^, count);
end;

procedure _free(P: Pointer); cdecl;
begin
 FreeMem(P);
end;

begin
end.
```

xxHash.o is 32bit for windows, build using MinGW 4.8.1. and the original sourcecode by Yann Collet in revision r36, included in [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/). Makefile is included.

Objectfile can be found on github [here](https://github.com/Hugie/lz4-delphi/blob/develop/lib/win32_mingw/xxhash.o)

Comment: renaming the functions did not help

Comment: That is [E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2065_Unsatisfied_forward_or_external_declaration_'%25s'_(Delphi)). As to why you encounter it, hard to say. If we could try to reproduce in a simple cut down project that might be useful.

Comment: How do i attach an object file here?

Comment: How did you make the object? Which compiler? Which target? You cannot attach an object here. It has to be offsite.

Comment: i added the necessary informations. MinGW with the delivered lz4 makefile, windows platform, x86.
Are there any known bugs for RadStudio XE3 when trying to link .o files?

Comment: I never managed to have success with mingw objects. I resorted to bcc32 for 32 bit and cl for 64 bit

Comment: OK, I've got your project from github and can reproduce. Odd I must say.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you've done a clean job of linking using MSVC. For instance, I know about `__chkstk` but the clean way to deal with that is to compile the MSVC objects with options that mean `__chkstk` is not called.

Comment: I thought about removing the msvc path. It was only for testing and the mingw path worked with less problems. (Except the xxh32 error here)

Comment: Which mingw did you use? How did you compile the objects? What command line? I have to say that I've never had any luck with mingw objects.

Comment: I reinstalled MinGW to reproduce the .o files.
Install MinGW, latest Version, install msys-base package with mingw-get, create a fstab file in MinGW\msys\1.0\etc, just rename fstab.sample to fstab, start MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat.
Then go to the lz4 directory and call make. Thats it.

Comment: ok, my bad.. i did not provide lz4 as source with the project. Maybbe i should consider this and add a "how to compile" doc to the project

Comment: Are you wed to doing this with mingw?

Comment: not realy... but: i have a solution. i added a dummy function before XXH32, which is now the first function... now i can link and it works :/

Comment: and the dummy function is not accessible/linkable. so XE3 does not find the first function in that .o file. But i do not understand why.

Comment: Hah! I was going to suggest you try that but it sounds silly doesn't it!

Comment: I should link this to embarcadero, maybe they have a bug..
it does not happen with the other .o files, since their first functions (looking at the dump files) are only internal functions.
But thank you for your help. Like most of the time, you just need to talk to someone about your errors ;)

Comment: this is the error of the year for me ;)

Comment: Definitely worth a bug report. Probably best to reproduce it with you own simple C function.

Comment: As for resolving dependencies a good trick is to use the `Crtl` unit. That gives you malloc etc.

Comment: Using the Crtl results in 2 E2065 for _calloc and __chkstk_ms with the project. I will take the non-crtl way, too much E2065 for today ;)

Comment: That makes no sense. Should not see __chkstk_ms with mingw. Your code needs simplifying quite a bit.

Comment: OK, I see __chkstk_ms with mingw which I now guess is because they use the msvc6 runtime msvcrt.dll. Still use Crtl but in addition let __chkstk_ms be provided by msvcrt.dll in the same vein as the rest of Crtl.

Comment: Interestingly I've now succeeded in linking mingw objects, but at runtime I face errors. Can't understand why it happens but the floating point loads of locals attempt to load absolute addresses rather than offsets from the base pointer. Do you see anything like that?

Comment: Error is reported at: [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=128802)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Workaround, also suggested by David Heffernan, is to add a dummy function to xxHash.c as first function.

The new dumpfile looks like this:

```
xxhash.o:     file format pe-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <_XXDUMMY>:
   0:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
   5:   c3                      ret    
   6:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
   9:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

00000010 <_XXH32>:
  10:   55                      push   %ebp
  11:   57                      push   %edi
  12:   56                      push   %esi
....
```

The project compiles with this hack, the error is gone.

Analyzing the other object files and trying to bind the first referenced functions always results in an error E2065.

There seems to be a general problem with using MinGW and gcc compiled .o files with Delphi.

Comment: Are you going to submit a bug report?

Comment: Yes, on monday when i am back at work. I will try this with xe7 before that. I only had xe3 ready yesterday.

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=128802
Bugreport is closed, no real feedback. Seems to be not a valid or allowed object file format. I am disapointed by the feedback given by ebc.

Comment: Yes, that is very poor indeed. I guess they don't care.